# Recording/tracking html slider control movement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I have a HTML5 slider (range) control in a phonegap/cordova app for iOS, using to calculate the commission on a real estate sale in a presentation - so you move the slider and it calculates the % based on the increasing sale price and a variable percentage as the sale price increases. All good.

Wondering if anyone knows a method to record the position of the slider?

The aim is to hand the iPad over to the punter, and when we get it back we can see the 'hot spots', so record the position say every 500ms or so.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: there is a slider in jquery ui that offers a bunch of events (e.g "change") which you could use for reading the current value and write it in an array. [jquery ui slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#event-change)

Answer (score 0):

Add a listener on that dom object and on change/mouseup, you can push the current value to an array.